# Get array of values instead of array of objects when using FOR JSON

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, for-json

I'm trying to flatten out an object array that is constructed by `FOR JSON`.

My query looks like:

```
select 
(                           
    select id from MyTable
    where id in (select value from OPENJSON(@jsonArray))
    FOR JSON PATH
) existing,                 
(   
    select value id from OPENJSON(@jsonArray) 
    where value not in (select Id from MyTable)
    FOR JSON PATH                       
) missing
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

The resulting JSON is:

```
{
    "existing": [
        {
            "id": "a00cd8f6-d1c6-4604-b235-59d3cacd5bcc"
        },
        {
            "id": "052455b6-6bf5-47d3-8bee-7ba98d7fbd50"
        }
    ],
    "missing": [
        {
            "id": "328add2d-e8f2-4a0e-af54-5b1733310170"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I would like instead is:

```
{
    "existing": [
        {
            "id": "a00cd8f6-d1c6-4604-b235-59d3cacd5bcc"
        },
        {
            "id": "052455b6-6bf5-47d3-8bee-7ba98d7fbd50"
        }
    ],
    "missing": [
        "328add2d-e8f2-4a0e-af54-5b1733310170"            
    ]
}
```

The missing array should not contain json-objects, just values. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server 2017 you can build your array with `JSON_QUERY` and `STRING_AGG` (with SQL Server 2016 you can't use `STRING_AGG`, so you'll have to do a bit of estra work, but the following idea would still be valid):

```
declare @missing table(id varchar(max))
declare @existing table(id varchar(max))

insert into @missing values ('a00cd8f6-d1c6-4604-b235-59d3cacd5bcc')
insert into @missing values ('052455b6-6bf5-47d3-8bee-7ba98d7fbd50')
insert into @existing values ('328add2d-e8f2-4a0e-af54-5b1733310170')

select  
(                           
    select id from @missing
    FOR JSON PATH
) existing,                
(   
    select JSON_QUERY(concat('[' , STRING_AGG(concat('"' , STRING_ESCAPE(id, 'json') , '"'),',') , ']')) 
    from @existing                 
) missing 
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

Result:

```
{
  "existing": [
    {
      "id": "a00cd8f6-d1c6-4604-b235-59d3cacd5bcc"
    },
    {
      "id": "052455b6-6bf5-47d3-8bee-7ba98d7fbd50"
    }
  ],
  "missing": [
    "328add2d-e8f2-4a0e-af54-5b1733310170"
  ]
}
```

Comment: `QUOTENAME` will not produce valid JSON if `id` contains any characters to escape. I suggest using `'"' + STRING_ESCAPE(id, 'json') + '"'` instead (even if it doesn't matter in the case of `id`s that are GUIDs).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Hadn't thought about that: you're absolutely right! I updated my answer including `STRING_ESCAPE`, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not as easy as it should be...

AFAIK there's no way to create a *naked* json array with sql-server. But you can trick this out on string level:

```
DECLARE @exist TABLE(id VARCHAR(100));
DECLARE @miss TABLE(id VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO @exist VALUES ('exist1'),('exist2');
INSERT INTO @miss VALUES ('miss1'),('miss2');
```

--This will create the object array you want

```
SELECT id FROM @exist
FOR JSON PATH
```

--And this will create the *naked* array using some rather ugly tricks.

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
(
    SELECT id from @miss
    FOR JSON PATH
),'"id":',''),'{',''),'}','')
```

--Now we have to combine both. And again we need a trick. We use `JSON_QUERY()` on the JSON literal to avoid escaped quotes.

```
SELECT
(
    SELECT id FROM @exist
    FOR JSON PATH
) AS existing
,JSON_QUERY(
   REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
    (
        SELECT id from @miss
        FOR JSON PATH
    ),'"id":',''),'{',''),'}','')
) AS missing
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```

This ist the result

```
{
  "existing":[{"id":"exist1"},{"id":"exist2"}]  <--array of objects
 ,"missing":["miss1","miss2"]                   <--array of naked values
}
```

I have no idea, why this can't be done *out-of-the-box*...

Comment: This doesn't work correctly if the JSON values themselves contain `{` or `}` characters -- these will be ruthlessly stripped out by the `REPLACE`. (No JSON value will contain `"id":` literally, of course, so that's still safe.)

Comment: This whole JSON feature in MS SQL Server seems incomplete to me.

Answer (score 0):

use append from a cursor

```
DECLARE @missing nvarchar(max),
    @json nvarchar(max) = (select 
                            (                           
                                select id from MyTable
                                where id in (select value from OPENJSON(@jsonArray))
                                FOR JSON PATH
                            ) existing
                            FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)

    DECLARE missing_cursor CURSOR FOR   
        select value id 
        from OPENJSON(@jsonArray)
        where value not in (select Id from MyTable)

        OPEN missing_cursor  

        FETCH NEXT FROM missing_cursor   
        INTO @missing

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
        BEGIN  
            SET @json = JSON_MODIFY(@json,'append $.missing', @missing)

            FETCH NEXT FROM missing_cursor   
            INTO @missing  
        END   
        CLOSE missing_cursor;  
        DEALLOCATE missing_cursor; 

    select @json
```